# How to localize text of PhoneCallManager windows mobile 10

Tags: c#, localization, uwp, windows-mobile, phone-call

I have windows mobile 10 app that supports multiple languages. Everything works well until I try to show phone call UI using PhoneCallManager class.

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI(model.Phone, model.Name);
```

When I make this call, phone call UI is shown, but the text is always in English.

Does anyone know how to localize this text?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, it will launch the built-in phone call UI that is always shown in the language of the phone.

Comment: But the language of the phone is changed to German in my case. And so are regional settings.